# php print email id with some part hidden

Tags: php

i have a variable which contains email id like

`axceasddfe.gdfs@cif.in` and `csderid.asldfj@xiz.com`

i want to show them first four characters and then `**` continue replacing the characters and then `@` and continue `**` and with `com` or `in`

**Example :**

```
$email_id = "axceasddfe.gdfs@cif.in";
$email_text = convertEmailFormat($email_id);

echo $email_text; // ouput axce**********@****in
```

I want `convertEmailFormat` function fo it.

Comment: Run a loop over it? Or you want something better?

Comment: quick'n'dirty: `$mail = preg_replace('/^(.{4})[^@]+@.+(.{2})$/', '$1***@***$2', $mail);` (shows always three *, not the correct number)

Comment: This is a request, not a question! A user with your experience should know better.

Comment: first thanks for all. sorry to be late respond by me. actually i can apply a logic for this but i placed it here because its used in very where to verify email address and send password to email address. so i think if there is a inbuilt or short method is available?

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
  function obscure_email($email){
       $email_array=explode('@', $email);
       $email_word=$email_array[0];
           $email_domain=$email_array[1];
       $obscured_email=substr($email_word, 0, 3);
       for($i=3; $i<strlen($email_word); $i++){
         $obscured_email.='*';
       }
           $obscured_email.='@';
           for($i=0; $i<strlen($email_domain)-2; $i++){
               $obscured_email.='*';
           }
       return $obscured_email.substr($email, -2, strlen($email));
   }
   echo obscure_email('test@testing.com');
```

prints:

```
   tes*@*********om
```

Answer (score 0):

i am providing the answer for my own question. i think there may be a short method or another logic. so any update or better solution will be appreciated.

```
function convertEmailFormat($email_id)
{
    $arr_temp = str_split($email_id);
    $email_text = "";
    $at =  0;
    $dot = 0;
    for($i=0; $i<sizeof($arr_temp); $i++)
    {
        $char = "*";
        if($i<4)
        {   
            $char = $arr_temp[$i];
            if($arr_temp[$i]=='@')
            {
                $at = 1;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if($arr_temp[$i]=='@')
            {
                $char = $arr_temp[$i];
                $at = 1;
            }
            else if($at==1 && $arr_temp[$i]=='.')
            {
                $dot=1;
            }
            else if($dot==1)
            {
                $char = $arr_temp[$i];
            }
        }

        $email_text .= $char;

    }
    return $email_text;
}
```